# Проблема в выполнении команды python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

При выполнении команды python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
получаю ошибку:

```
2021-11-10 09:17:25.209316: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kamil\Documents\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch
  File "C:\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\ssd_meta_arch.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils
  File "C:\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Вот инструкция которую я использую:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#cuda-install
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Установите matplotlib.

`pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\kamil\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\kamil\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in c:\programdata\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ...
Requirement already satisfied: ...
Requirement already satisfied: ...
Requirement already satisfied: ...
Requirement already satisfied: ...

Comment: Есть ли еще варинты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: `pip uninstall matplotlib` `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но к сожалению это не решило мою проблему...